# What can one do with PayPal API keys

Tags: paypal

In case one is asked to enter their PayPal API keys (API user, API password, API signature), what can the receiving end actually do with those?

The receiving end wants to use the keys for Express Checkout and that's fine, but I'm not sure whether giving such information would actually enable the other party to make use of other functionality (such as having a look at the balance of the account).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can have a look at [PayPal's REST API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) to see what can be done with an API key. I'm not aware of any way to grant subsets of permissions to an API key (but I don't know for sure that it's impossible, either).

There's also [the SOAP API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/). I haven't used it, so I'm not entirely sure if it uses the same API keys or some separate authorization mechanism. It does contain a [`GetBalance` API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetBalance_API_Operation_NVP/), though.

It should perhaps be noted that I don't think it should be considered impossible that PayPal extends the API-accessible functionality at any time, though.